# How to model two one-to-one relationships between the same two tables in Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a table, `dataset_pair_visualization`, of hierarchical clustering visualizations:

```
+--------------+--------------+-------+------+
| dataset_1_fk | dataset_2_fk | image | link |
+--------------+--------------+-------+------+
```

Each row in the table has two foreign keys to two different rows in the `dataset` table. How can I model this using Hibernate's annotations? Is the relationship one-to-one or one-to-many? I don't want a `Set` or `List` of `Dataset` instances. I want to reference two specific datasets.

My attempt:

**DatasetPairVisualization.java**

```
public class DatasetPairVisualization {

    ...

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "dataset_1_fk")
    private Dataset dataset1;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "dataset_2_fk")
    private Dataset dataset2;

    ...
```

**Dataset.java**

```
public class Dataset {

    ...

    // But one Dataset should map to one DatasetPairVisualization
    // What should this look like? "dataset" is obviously wrong,
    // since the properties are "dataset1" and "dataset2"
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "dataset")
    private DatasetPairVisualization datasetPairVisualization1;

    ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a '**ManyToOne**' relationship in which '**Many**' (two to be exact) `Dataset` are related to '**One**' `DatasetPairVisualization`. So you have to map them as such:

```
public class DatasetPairVisualization {

    ...

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "dataset_1_fk")
    private Dataset dataset1;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "dataset_2_fk")
    private Dataset dataset2;

    ...
```

The usual way of modelling a '**ManyToOne**' in the database would be to have a foreign key from `Dataset` to `DatasetPairVisualization`. But since you have the FKs in the other table and they are limited to only two occurrences, I don't see a proper way of doing a bidirectional mapping.

If it's not of vital importance to be able to navigate the relationship **from** `Dataset` **to** `DatasetPairVisualization` I would leave it as it is, and not declare any mapping in the `Dataset` entity.